# Powershell error handling

Tags: powershell

Take the below example.

```
Function Test-Function {
    try {
        [int]$var.ToString()
    }catch{
        Write-Error "Error inside Function"     
    }
}


try {
    Test-Function
}catch{
    Write-Error "Error inside try/catch of script"
}
```

`Test-Function` itself is generating an error (on purpose in this case, to test this behaviour), therefore hitting it's own catch. However, the Function call itself within the script, is also wrapped in a Try Catch statement, but the script only ever displays the catch of the function. Is this behaviour by design?

Comment: In .Net C# I've seen this many times and it's ok. When `Test-Function` catches an exception, error message it's more specific and that's the reason for nesting try/catch blocks. I personally don't do that but I re-throw the exception inside Test-Function catch block with new more descriptive error message so I only have to call my Logger once in the parent at the bottom of call stack. Here there's no Logger object, just a Write-Error, so it's ok. However I still prefer my method, as it aborts all execution at first error. **Whereas the code you posted allows inconsistent code to keep running**

Comment: I'm not sure I follow. Why doesn't the try catch calling the function catch an error?

Comment: because the error was already caught

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is how `try`-`catch` works and what `Write-Error` does. From [Doc.Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-error?view=powershell-5.1) we know that....

> The Write-Error cmdlet declares a **non-terminating** error

And looking at [About_Try_Catch_Finally](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_try_catch_finally?view=powershell-5.1) we see that it...

> Describes how to use the Try, Catch, and Finally blocks to handle **terminating** errors.

<sup>Emphasis mine in both quotes</sup>

Try catch is not going to capture the output from `Write-Error` and that is by design. If you want to pass a terminating error use `throw`

```
Function Test-Function {
    try {
        [int]$var1.ToString()
    }catch{
        throw "Error inside Function"     
    }
}
```